# How to calculate the discrete First Order Derivative of a function f using a Matrix Differential Operator in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, derivative, finite-difference

I want to calculate a discrete approximation of *df/dx* in Matlab using a vector *f* representing the function and a Matrix *D* representing a differential operator. *f* in this example is a simple sine wave such that the *df/dx* should be *cos(x)*.

The differential approximation *df/dx* seems to be correct but the amplitude scaling is incorrect and the last and first samples are out of line. Why?

**Matlab code:**

```
%% Sandbox Finite Difference
clear
clc
close all

% set physical values
f=1000;
c=343.21;
lambda=c/f;
w=2*pi*f;
k=w/c;
dx=0.01;
x_max=1;
x=0:dx:x_max;

% initialize function f
f=sin(k.*x);

% Build Differential Operator D
di= ones(1,length(f)-1);
D = diag(di,1);
D = D+diag(-di,-1);
% scale D with 1/(2*dx)
D = D*(1/(2*dx));

% Apply Differential Operator on f
f_1diff=D*f';

% plot f and df/dx
plot(f)
hold on
plot(f_1diff)
```

Comment: The first and last being wrong is easy: check what the matrix rows are for those values. Its only either +1 or -1, you don't have both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scaling factor for D should be `1/(2*dx*k)`. as the derivative of `f(x)/dx` contains `k` as constant.

Also, the end points are wrong because you have not considered what boundary conditions you give your operator. The first row is `scale*[0 1 0 ....]`, there is no `-1`. You decide how to handle this, but of course no decision is perfect because the value you need does not exist (`f(0)`, or `f(end+1)` for the other side.